# Reading from URL: Error

Tags: java, url

I am trying to read from a URL but my program constantly gives me this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://www.google.com/search?q=weather+in+seattle&oq=weather+in+sea&aqs=chrome.0.0l3j69i57j0l2.4686j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1913)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1117)
at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Main.main(Main.java:25)

What must I do to fix this?

Comment: What is `Main.java:25` line?

Comment: Add the code which you are using to read from the URL.

Comment: @Roshana Pitigala Never mind, I fixed it. But thanks so much for responding so quickly!

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to add the solution an answer, it may help the future readers.

Comment: For future readers, the reason was that the url did not contain the information I wanted. Hence my object was never created, so a NullPointerException arose.